# About pop() and push() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm really a beginner in Javascript, and trying what i read as much as I can.

But when comes to `pop()` and `push()`, I get some strange results that I'm wondering about.

Here's the code :

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(2,3);
console.log(arr);

console.log(arr.pop());
console.log(arr);
```

the result is :

> [2, undefined × 1]
>
> 3
>
> [2]

Shouldn't it be :

> [2, 3]
>
> 3
>
> [2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to `console.log`'s asynchronous evaluation on your browser. By the time the result of the first `console.log` has been displayed, the item is already gone because of `pop()`.

For accurate results, call `toString()`:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(2,3);
console.log(arr.toString()); // 2,3 - as expected.

console.log(arr.pop());
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: But how comes .toString() made the difference although console.log is still there ?

Comment: @Rafael: `.toString()` converts the array to a string synchronously, and passes that string to `console.log` before `pop()` is called. The asynchronicity of `console.log` on certain browsers is a special case compared to the rest of JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to note that the console handles objects as "live". Any object (arrays, objects etc.) you already outputted on the console is still subject to operations.

That's why when you expected `[2,3]` on the first log, the code already popped the 3, thus replaced `undefined` on 3's spot.

Of course, this event depends on how the browser implement's their console.

Comment: This happens with safari and chrome console but not with firefox's console

Comment: if so the stack should be [2].